# 2D Colliders not colliding [Unity - C#]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider, urp

I did some research, but nothing really helped me. I followed step by step tutorials, but nothing helped too.

I'm in Unity 2022.3.11f1 and my project is a 2D URP project. I am doing a platformer using Tilemaps, and I have tested a lot of configurations, but my tilemaps don't collide with other objects of the scene.

Here is the Tilemap configuration:
[Tilemap configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9CNk.png)

Here is the Player configuration:
[Player configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4atng.png)

I hoped that you could link me to some references or tutos. If you have the answer, I also would be pleased to read it.

Thanks to you and have a good day.

Comment: Did you set up collision matrix? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Comment: @Morion Yes, the collision matrix is set up so that every layer can collide with every layer